# Datepicker set the selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

This is my code, the page is called Cal.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#datascelta',
        onSelect: function(){
          $('#formscelta').submit();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div id="datepicker"></div>
  <form id="formscelta" action="Cal.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="datascelta" id="datascelta">
  </form>
</head>
```

Want I wanna do is when I select the date in the datepicker and the page is reloaded I would like to set the date in the datepicker to the previously selected date. Is it possible?

Comment: Your code is not valid. You can not have html tags inside your *<head>*.

Comment: Do you want to keep the selected date unchanged even if the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 1):

To store date and get it after reloading page you have to use cookies, so you can use cookies (`js-cookie` or `jquery cookie`) or use `localStorage`, see code exmples bellow :

Using **[js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)** :

```
Cookies.set('datascelta', dataValue); //set datascelta
Cookies.get('datascelta'); //get datascelta
```

**Full code :**

```
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#datascelta',
        defaultDate: Cookies.get('datascelta') ? Cookies.get('datascelta') : new Date() //get the date after reload and init datepicker
        onSelect: function (dataValue) {
            Cookies.set('datascelta', dataValue); //store the date in cookies before submiting form
            $('#formscelta').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Or you can use **[jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)** :

```
$.cookie('datascelta', dataValue);  //set datascelta
$.cookie('datascelta');  //get datascelta
```

**Full code :**

```
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#datascelta',
        defaultDate: $.cookie('datascelta') ? $.cookie('datascelta') : new Date() //get the date after reload and init datepicker
        onSelect: function (dataValue) {
            $.cookie('datascelta', dataValue); //store the date in cookies before submiting form
            $('#formscelta').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

You can also use `Localstorage` take a look at **[local storage vs cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)**.

Using a **[Local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)** the code will be like following :

```
localStorage['datascelta'] = dataValue;  //set datascelta
localStorage['datascelta'];  //get datascelta
```

**Full code :**

```
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#datascelta',
        defaultDate: localStorage['datascelta'] ? localStorage['datascelta'] : new Date() //get the date after reload and init datepicker
        onSelect: function (dataValue) {
            localStorage['datascelta'] = dataValue; //store the date in cookies before submiting form
            $('#formscelta').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to set the value from calendar to the hidden field before you can submit the value to server.

```
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#datascelta',
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            $('#datascelta').val(dateText); //setting hidden field value
            $('#formscelta').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you need to do is, when we select a date and reload the page, keep it as the selected date.

You can do it by saving the selected date in the `localStorage` and reading it whenever the page is reloaded, and setting it as the selected date.

Inside the `onchange` event, you should store the selected date in `localStorage`,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     inline: true,
     altField: '#datascelta',
     onSelect: function () {
         localStorage.setItem("lastSelectedDate", $(this).val());
         $('#formscelta').submit();
     }
 });
```

When the page is loaded, you should check whether the `localStorage` item for the key of `lastSelectedDate` exists, and if so, set it to that value by casting it to a `Date` object.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("lastSelectedDate") != "") {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", 
        new Date(localStorage.getItem("lastSelectedDate")));
}
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/arunatebel/h1qxv6nz/3/) is a working example